# Is it technically possible to rely on a heter from a rabbi you have never met?

Tags: halacha-theory, contemporary-halacha

This is probably a stupid question, but I was wondering if it's possible to rely on a controversial heter that's not generally accepted.

For example Rav Messas was matir for married women uncovering their hair. If a Moroccan Jewish woman chooses to follow this heter even though all other Sephardi later rabbis didn't hold like this, are they technically doing an aveirah?

Comment: We all follow rabbis all the time we never met, like those in the Shulchan Aruch etc. I would imagine someone who follows all the rulings of Rav Messas could rely on this, but not to cherry pick leniencies.

Comment: Yes it is possible. And if you believe me, then you prove that you already knew the answer, since we have never met. Welcome to Mi Yodeya :) Nice meeting You.

Comment: Nice to meet you too ! :)

Comment: Just to clarify ,he didn't give a heter ,he was being melamed zechus on the current custom

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Forouzan and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!